# strsplit: split strings from integers

Tags: r

I'm currently writing a code to use strsplit to separate letters from integers, as one of my exam practice / study session (ungraded for this matter, and I wasn't able to grasp the concept just yet).

I tried:

```
unlist(strsplit(s, "(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9])"))
```

but this doesn't work.

also tried

```
unlist(strsplit(s, ""))
```

but this gives me just vector of `char`, not essentially separating letters from integers.

For example, instead of `"w17u2"` becoming `"w"`, `"1"`, `"7"`, `"u"`, `"2"` I need it to be `"w"`, `"17"`, `"u"`, `"2"`.

There won't be any specific pattern to the input, so it must be able to separate letters from integers at any pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to use look-aheads/look-behinds

```
ss <- "w17u2"

unlist(strsplit(ss, "((?<=[a-z])(?![a-z])|(?<=\\d)(?!\\d))", perl = T))
#[1] "w"  "17" "u"  "2"
```

Explanation:

`(?<=[a-z])(?![a-z])` splits the string at the position where the *preceding* character matches `[a-z]` and the *following* character does not match `[a-z]`. Similarly, `(?<=\\d)(?!\\d)` splits the string at the position where the *preceding* character matches a digit and the *following* character does not match a digit. The final regular expression is the OR concatenation of both regex patterns.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use strsplit twice, say:

```
splitnums <- function(s) {
  v1 <- strsplit(s, '\\d+')[[1]] # "aa" "ss" "d"  "f"
  v2 <- strsplit(s, '\\D+')[[1]] # ""   "2"  "3"  "22" "5" 
  if (v1[1] == "") return(c(rbind(v2, v1[2:length(v1)])))
  else return(c(rbind(v1, v2[2:length(v2)])))
}

splitnums('aa2ss3d22f5')
# [1] "aa" "2"  "ss" "3"  "d"  "22" "f"  "5"
```